# Round values on serialization when using XmlSerializer to serialize to an XML string

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm using **XmlSerializer** to serialize my object model to XML.  At the moment just prior to serilization I'm recusively going through my entire model and rounding any values to 1 or 2 decimal places depending on some property.

Is there a way to do this by subclassing the XmlSerializer.  I tried overriding the protected override void Serialize(object o, XmlSerializationWriter writer) method but it is never called.

Here is my block of code that does the serialisation:

```
 StringWriter writer = new Utf8StringWriter();

 XmlWriter xml = XmlWriter.Create(writer, new XmlWriterSettings() { Encoding = writer.Encoding });

 new MySubClassSerializer(engine.GetType()).Serialize(xml, engine);
```

My subclassed serializer does not do anything at the moment just subclasses to it's parent.

Comment: Instead of manually having to round each field in each class by name, you might be able to use reflection to search for floating point fields and round them all programmatically.

Comment: @Moozhe So I would still have to recursively go over my model checking for property names and setting as required.  I was hoping to avoid this extra overhead considering I assume the XMLSerializer does this type of thing already?  Well, actually I was hoping for a more elegant solution using the existing XMLSerializer classes etc

Comment: Right.  Speed wise it wouldn't be fast, but code wise it would require very little code and you could add fields and not have to update your existing serialization code.  You could also implement IXmlSerializable and write the serialization yourself.  Theoretically this would be just as fast as the normal way, but it would be more code on your part.  I don't think you can get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you wrapped these values in another property?  Like this:

```
[XmlIgnore()]
public float SomeValue { get; set; }

[XmlAttribute("SomeValue")]
public float SomeValueRounded
{
    get { return (float)Math.Round(SomeValue, 2); }
    set { SomeValue = value; }
}
```

Comment: I have contemplated that but there are a heck of a lot of properties that I would need to do this too.  I was hoping to have to avoid this kind of approach if i can get away with it.